# Change Font Size, color in GridView while loading

Tags: android, grid

I am using `GridView` in Android to show the data. I want to change the size and color of the text while loading the grid. I can do it on grid item click by using

```
objGridDays.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
       {
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) 
           {
               ((TextView) v).setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
               ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
               ((TextView) v).setTextSize(15);             
           }

       });
```

I want to do the same operation while loading the grid.

Comment: Where exactly you are inflating this textView to your grid?

Answer (score 0):

please set this code in getView method in GridView Adapter:

```
           ((TextView) v).setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
           ((TextView) v).setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
           ((TextView) v).setTextSize(15);
```

and best way to choose grid_item and change textview xml code like:

```
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
android:textSize="15"
```